# Objective-C the ^ operator

Tags: ios, objective-c

I'm a newbie in Objective C and trying to figure out what does the ^ operator? While exploring some source code i saw next construction:

```
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(CGSizeMake(20.f, 13.f), NO, 0.0f);

    [[UIColor blackColor] setFill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, 20, 1)] fill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 5, 20, 1)] fill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 10, 20, 1)] fill];

    [[UIColor whiteColor] setFill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 1, 20, 2)] fill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 6,  20, 2)] fill];
    [[UIBezierPath bezierPathWithRect:CGRectMake(0, 11, 20, 2)] fill];   

    defaultImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

});
```

And I'd like to know what is the ^?

Comment: Read this: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html

Comment: @DanielSchneller I would say that it is because, in this case it is very difficult to search for documentation  on blocks if you don't know what they are called. You could read the Objective-C guide but it's not the best way to learn.

Comment: @RogerNolan I completely agree with you, thank you.

Comment: Alright. Point taken. However, searching for "^" on http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Objective-C would have led to an answer immediately.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The `^` indicated the start of a block definition within Objective-C.

Have a look in here: http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxGettingStarted.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007502-CH7-SW1

Note that in this context, the `^` is not an operator, it is part of the syntax of Objective-C  @Mike's down-voted answer is strictly the correct definition of the "^ operator"

Comment: @RogerNolan I'm not sure that I agree with your statement. In both uses `^` is an operator, just used in a different way, to accomplish different results. Top of the head comparison is `=` and `==`.

Comment: I guess it's not that important but I think that ^ (block) is a part of the language syntax - the same as `int` it is a definition supplying meaning to the following token. Operators cause 'execution' and have 'results'. This `^` is part of a definition of a lambda. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operator_(computer_programming)

Answer (score 6):

It is called a **Block** In Objective C

Syntax:

```
returnType (^variableName)(parameters);
```

Taken verbatim from a [tutorial by Akiel Khan](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/understanding-objective-c-blocks--mobile-14319), (you can find another good tutorial [here](https://web.archive.org/web/20131025011421/http://informalprotocol.com/2012/10/declaring-blocks-in-objective-c)) :

> - The block literal is “anonymous” (i.e. nameless)
> - The caret (^) symbol
> - We didn’t have to specify the return type – the compiler can “infer” it. We could’ve explicitly mentioned it if we wanted to.

[This is a Official Documentation, read it for more information.](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithBlocks/WorkingwithBlocks.html)

Answer (score 4):

Here it is a signal for beginning a block.

You can find more information of block by reading some tutorial blogs or articles:

[Blocks – An Interesting Objective-C Addition In iOS 4](http://maniacdev.com/2010/07/blocks-an-interesting-objective-c-addition-in-ios-4/)

[How To Use Blocks in iOS 5 Tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/9438/how-to-use-blocks-in-ios-5-tutorial-part-2)

When you know the basic thing of block, you can refer to [Apple's document about block](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html).

In fact, the most regular use of block will be [GCD](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Performance/Reference/GCD_libdispatch_Ref/Reference/reference.html)(stands for Grand Central Dispatch, which is your case in question), [UIView's animation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIView_Class/UIView/UIView.html#//apple_ref/occ/cl/UIView) and something other like a callback. It is very useful and common in modern Obj-C programming.

Comment: Thank you for additional links!

Answer (score 2):

It is used to create blocks in object c blocks are just like function pointers in c. This may help you

[checkout this link](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/Blocks/Articles/00_Introduction.html)

Comment: Thank you for additional links!